# How do I generate the data from my handleparse variable onto my invoicemodal variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like my parsed files to generate on my preview window shown on the image. My parsed data is generated by the handleparse variable. Once in the preview window the data generated there is generated as a pdf

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import { BiCloudDownload } from 'react-icons/bi';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

const GenerateInvoice = () => {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#invoiceCapture")).then((canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'portrait',
      unit: 'pt',
      format: [612, 792]
    });
    pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 1;
    const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
    pdf.save('invoice-001.pdf');
  });
};

const InvoiceModal = ({ showModal, closeModal, info, data1, data2 }) => {
  const tableData1 = data1.map((row) => {
    const [LastName, FirstName, Hours] = [
    row[Object.keys(row)[0]],
    row[Object.keys(row)[2]],
    row[Object.keys(row)[11]],
  ];
  return [LastName, FirstName, Hours];
});
  const tableData2 = data2.map((row) => {
    const [firstColumn, fifthColumn] = [
    row[Object.keys(row)[0]],
    row[Object.keys(row)[4]],
  ];
  return [firstColumn, fifthColumn];
});

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={closeModal} size="lg" centered>
        <div id="invoiceCapture">
          <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-start bg-light w-100 p-4">
            <div className="w-100">
              <h4 className="fw-bold my-2">{info.billFrom || 'RoviSys'}</h4>
              <h6 className="fw-bold text-secondary mb-1">
                Invoice #: {info.invoiceNumber || ''}
              </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="p-4">
            <Row className="mb-4">
              <Col md={4}>
                <div className="fw-bold">Basic Info:</div>
                <div>{info.billFrom || ''}</div>
                <div>{info.billFromAddress || ''}</div>
                <div>{info.billFromEmail || ''}</div>
              </Col>
              <Col md={4}>
                <div className="fw-bold">&nbsp;</div>
                <div>{info.billTo || ''}</div>
                <div>{info.billToAddress || ''}</div>
                <div>{info.billToEmail || ''}</div>
              </Col>
              <Col md={4}>
                <div className="fw-bold mt-2">Period of Invoice Data:</div>
                <div>
                  {info.dateOfIssue || ''} - {info.dateOfIssueEnd || ''}
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>

            <Table striped bordered hover>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Hours</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {tableData1.map((rowData, index) => (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    {rowData.map((data, idx) => (
                      <td key={idx}>{data}</td>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </Table>

            <Table striped bordered hover>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Resource Level</th>
                  <th>Rate</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {tableData2.map((rowData, index) => (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    {rowData.map((data, idx) => (
                      <td key={idx}>{data}</td>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </Table>

            {info.notes && (
              <div className="bg-light py-3 px-4 rounded">{info.notes}</div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="pb-4 px-4">
          <Row>
            <Col md={6}></Col>
            <Col md={6}>
              <Button
                variant="outline-primary"
                className="d-block w-100 mt-3 mt-md-0"
                onClick={GenerateInvoice}
              >
                <BiCloudDownload
                  style={{ width: '16px', height: '16px', marginTop: '-3px' }}
                  className="me-2"
                />
                Download Copy
              </Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </Modal>
      <hr className="mt-4 mb-3" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InvoiceModal;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import InvoiceModal from './InvoiceModal';
import Papa from "papaparse";
import JsPDF from 'jspdf';
import "jspdf-autotable";

const InvoiceForm = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isOpen: false,
    currentDate: '',
    invoiceNumber: 1,
    dateOfIssue: '',
    dateOfIssueEnd: '',
    billTo: '',
    billToEmail: '',
    billToAddress: '',
    billFrom: '',
    billFromEmail: '',
    billFromAddress: '',
    notes: '',
  });

  const editField = (event) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const openModal = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setState({ ...state, isOpen: true });
  };

  const closeModal = (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, isOpen: false });
  };

  const allowedExtensions = ["csv"];

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [file2, setFile2] = useState("");

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files.length) {
      const inputFile = e.target.files[0];
      const fileExtension = inputFile?.name.split(".").pop();
      if (!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
        setError("Please input a csv file");
        return;
      }
      setFile(inputFile);
    }
  };

  const handleFileChange2 = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files.length) {
      const inputFile = e.target.files[0];
      const fileExtension = inputFile?.name.split(".").pop();
      if (!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
        setError("Please input a csv file");
        return;
      }
      setFile2(inputFile);
    }
  };

  const handleParse = () => {
    if (!file || !file2) return setError("Enter valid files");

    const reader1 = new FileReader();
    reader1.onload = function (e) {
      const csv1 = e.target.result;
      const parsedData1 = Papa.parse(csv1, { header: true }).data;
      const reader2 = new FileReader();
      reader2.onload = function (e) {
        const csv2 = e.target.result;
        const parsedData2 = Papa.parse(csv2, { header: true }).data;
        generatePDF(parsedData1, parsedData2);
      };
      reader2.readAsText(file2);
    };
    reader1.readAsText(file);
  };

  const generatePDF = (data1, data2) => {
    const doc = new JsPDF();
    // const tableData1 = data1.map((row) => {
    //   const [LastName, FirstName, Hours] = [
    //     row[Object.keys(row)[0]],
    //     row[Object.keys(row)[2]],
    //     row[Object.keys(row)[11]],
    //   ];
    //   return [LastName, FirstName, Hours];
    // });
    // const tableData2 = data2.map((row) => {
    //   const [firstColumn, fifthColumn] = [
    //     row[Object.keys(row)[0]],
    //     row[Object.keys(row)[4]],
    //   ];
    //   return [firstColumn, fifthColumn];
    // });

    // doc.autoTable({
    //   head: [['LastName', ' FirstName', ' Hours']],
    //   body: tableData1,
    //   theme: 'grid',
    //   styles: {
    //     lineColor: [0, 0, 0],
    //     lineWidth: 0.4,
    //     textColor: [0, 0, 0]
    //   },
    //   headStyles: { fillColor: [255, 255, 255], textColor: [0, 0, 0] },
    //   margin: { top: 20 },
    // });

    // doc.autoTable({
    //   startY: doc.lastAutoTable.finalY + 15,
    //   head: [['Resource Level', 'Rate']],
    //   body: tableData2,
    //   theme: 'grid',
    //   styles: {
    //     lineColor: [0, 0, 0], 
    //     lineWidth: 0.4,
    //     textColor: [0, 0, 0]
    //   },
    //   headStyles: { fillColor: [255, 255, 255], textColor: [0, 0, 0] }, 
    //   margin: { top: 20 },
    // });

    doc.save('CombinedData.pdf');
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={openModal}>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8} lg={9}>
          <Card className="p-4 p-xl-5 my-3 my-xl-4">
            <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-between mb-3">
              <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                  <div className="mb-2">
                    <span className="fw-bold">Current&nbsp;Date:&nbsp;</span>
                    <span className="current-date">{new Date().toLocaleDateString()}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
                  <span className="fw-bold d-block me-2">Invoice Period:</span>
                  <Row className="mb-5">
                    <Col>
                      <Form.Label className="fw-bold">Start Date:</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="date"
                        value={state.dateOfIssue}
                        name="dateOfIssue"
                        onChange={editField}
                        style={{ maxWidth: '150px' }}
                        required
                      />
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <Form.Label className="fw-bold">End Date:</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="date"
                        value={state.dateOfIssueEnd}
                        name="dateOfIssueEnd"
                        onChange={editField}
                        style={{ maxWidth: '150px' }}
                        required
                      />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
                <span className="fw-bold me-2">Invoice&nbsp;Number:&nbsp;</span>
                <Form.Control
                  type="number"
                  value={state.invoiceNumber}
                  name="invoiceNumber"
                  onChange={editField}
                  min="1"
                  style={{ maxWidth: '70px' }}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr className="my-4" />
            <Row className="mb-5">
              <Col>
                <Form.Label className="fw-bold">Basic Info:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  rows={3}
                  value="RoviSys"
                  type="text"
                  name="billFrom"
                  className="my-2"
                  onChange={editField}
                  autoComplete="name"
                  required
                  readOnly="readonly"
                />
                  <Form.Control
                  placeholder={"Project Name"}
                  value={state.billFromEmail}
                  type="text"
                  name="billFromEmail"
                  className="my-2"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  onChange={editField}
                  required
                />
                <Form.Control
                  placeholder={"Purchase Order"}
                  value={state.billFromAddress}
                  type="text"
                  name="billFromAddress"
                  className="my-2"
                  autoComplete="address"
                  onChange={editField}
                  required
                />
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Form.Label className="fw-bold"><span>&shy;</span></Form.Label>
                <Col style={{ marginBottom: '28px' }}>&nbsp;</Col>
                <Form.Control
                  placeholder={"Project Number"}
                  value={state.billTo}
                  type="text"
                  name="billTo"
                  className="my-2"
                  onChange={editField}
                  autoComplete="name"
                  required
                />
                <Form.Control
                  placeholder={"Report Title"}
                  value={state.billToEmail}
                  type="text"
                  name="billToEmail"
                  className="my-2"
                  onChange={editField}
                  autoComplete="email"
                  required
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
           
            <div>
              <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
                <Form.Label>Enter Teams.csv File  </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={handleFileChange} id="csvInput" name="file" type="file" />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
                <Form.Label>Enter InvoiceRates.csv File</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={handleFileChange2} id="csvInput2" name="file2" type="file" />
              </Form.Group>
              <Button onClick={handleParse} className="fw-bold btn-secondary">Submit</Button>
            </div>

            <hr className="my-4" />
            <Form.Label className="fw-bold">Notes:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="Thank you for doing business with us!"
              name="notes"
              value={state.notes}
              onChange={editField}
              as="textarea"
              className="my-2"
              rows={1}
            />
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4} lg={3}>
          <div className="sticky-top pt-md-3 pt-xl-4">
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="d-block w-100 btn-dark">
              Review Invoice
            </Button>
            <InvoiceModal showModal={state.isOpen} closeModal={closeModal} info={state}/>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default InvoiceForm;
```

I've tried passing the data through props but I am unsure how to pass it through. I also generated a table that would show on my preview window, I just need to pass data through it.